# How to trim or strip white spaces from a String while using Robot Framework

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

How to trim or strip white spaces from a String while using Robot Framework

If I have a string " Hello How are you  "
how to convert it to "HelloHowareyou" (stripping all the white spaces)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Also ${str.strip()} works. It uses the [Extended variable syntax](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) Example:

```
*** Variables ***
${str}=    ${SPACE}${SPACE}${SPACE}foo${SPACE}${SPACE}${SPACE}

*** Test cases ***
print string
    log    ${str}         # will be printed with spaces around it
    log    ${str.strip()} # will be printed without spaces around it
```

Run with pybot -L TRACE to see what is being passed to log keyword.

Comment: this offers a lot  more possibilities while playing with strings - thanks

Comment: Note that strip defaults to removing preceding/trailing spaces, but also works handily to remove enclosing quotes when you give it a parameter like `yourvar.strip('"')`

Comment: I wish to add that you can use any other python library directly in RF, like os,sys etc, its pretty useful

Comment: This only removes spaces around it. Since Robotframework 3.0 this can also be done with Strip String in the String library. To remove all spaces from the string use the solution from Grant McCloskey.

Answer (score 4):

```
${time_stamp}=       Get Time
${time_stamp}=       Evaluate    '${time_stamp}'.replace(' ','_')
```

Might also be useful

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a python function, or using regular expressions.

### MyLibrary.py

```
def Remove_Whitespace(instring):
    return instring.strip()
```

### MySuite.txt

```
| *Setting* | *Value* |
| Library   | String        
| Library   | ./MyLibrary.py

| *Test Case* | *Action* | *Argument*
| T100 | [Documentation] | Removes leading and trailing whitespace from a string.
       # whatever you need to do to get ${myString}
|      | ${tmp}= | Remove Whitespace | ${myString}
       # ${tmp} is ${myString} with the leading and trailing whitespace removed.
| T101 | [Documentation] | Removes leading and trailing whitespace from a string.
       # whatever you need to do to get ${myString}
       # The \ is needed to create an empty string in this format
|      | ${tmp}= | Replace String Using Regexp | ${myString} | (^[ ]+|[ ]+$) | \
       # ${tmp} is ${myString} with the leading and trailing whitespace removed.
```

Comment: this was what I was doing earlier, now I would rather use the way that the accepted answer recommends, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Most better way is to use pure Robot Framework keywords [Remove String](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Remove%20String) and [Replace String](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Replace%20String) both this keywords does used [replace()](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/robot/libraries/String.html#String.replace_string) function internally but makes your code more readable than other options. Also you may want to look at [Strip String](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Strip%20String) which is new in RF v 3.0

**Example 1** -

```
${Result}=    Remove String    Hello How are you    ${SPACE}
```

Output 1 -

[image]

**Example 2** -

```
${Result2}=   Replace String     Hello How are you    ${SPACE}        ${EMPTY}
```

Output 2 -
[image]

Note: [${SPACE}, ${EMPTY}](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#space-and-empty-variables) are built in variable of robot framework.