# Is there a way to remove whitespace in a JSON reply before comparing in RobotFramework?

Tags: json, robotframework

I am receiving a JSON reply using HTTP-Post with the RobotFramework HttpLibray, the issue I have with some returned data is value's sometimes get returned with extra spaces in the value.  I'd like to be able to strip out trailing spaces in the values before doing a JSON compare, and I would like to keep the JSON format after stripping out any trailing white spaces.  I do a compare against an expected response so I want to keep the format for comparison.

Is there an easy way to do this so I can look at the JSON reply and maintain it in the correct format, but without trailing spaces?

What I encounter is something like the following, where I want to remove all the space after the title value, for example:

```
    { 
      account: [  
        title: "Dr.      "  
      ]  
    }
```

I don't have the capability to change the source data, so I would like to be able to handle this when receiving the JSON response in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you can't change source data but I'm assuming you can pull out specific JSON nodes, store in a var and then manipulate before comparison?

If so string operations become very helpful.  If this is an option you could then use

```
${jsonNode.strip()}
```

You can find more information in this previous answer:

[How to trim or strip white spaces from a String while using Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832094/how-to-trim-or-strip-white-spaces-from-a-string-while-using-robot-framework)

Comment: To remove trailing whitespace but not leading whitespace use rstrip() instead of strip(). Also keep in mind that r/l/strip() remove all whitespace and not just spaces. To remove only trailing spaces, and not tabs, you could do: ${trimmed}    Replace String Using Regexp    ${data}    ${SPACE}+\\Z    ${EMPTY}

Comment: Good to know about the two methods, I can see where both will come in handy